# how to use django model object in django templates?

Tags: python, django

I am not able to use the Django model object in Django templates. I want to iterate using the model user in the template and then play with the  ActivityPeriod(model) of that user. Please check my code for the clarity:

Here is my code:

views.py

```
from .models import User,ActivityPeriod

def call_response(request):
    user = User.objects.all()
    return render(request, "Test/list.html", {"users":user ,"activityperiod":ActivityPeriod})
```

Test/list.html

```
{% for user in users %}
    'real_name': {{ user.real_name}}},
    'activity_periods': {% with activity=activityperiod.objects.get(id =user) %}
    {{ activity.start_time }}
    {% endwith %}
{% endfor %}
```

But i am getting an error:
**Could not parse the remainder: '(id' from 'activityperiod.objects.get(id'**

What is the correct way? Can anyone please share it with me.

Answer (score 2):

Django template doesn't understand the filter action of Model. This part shoud be in view.

```
activity=activityperiod.objects.get(id =user)
```

You should prepare your data and manipulate them before sending to template (a dictionary may help you). And remember that result of  action "User.objects.all()" is a list.

Comment: But how to achieve it. I am iterating over the model Users in the template. Now I want to get the information from the model "ActivityPeriod" but how do I get it from the views?

Comment: Iterate the user list and retrieve the activity of user. You can save a list of dictionary like that: [{'user': usr_obj[0], 'activity': act[0]},.....]. Hope that help!

Answer (score 1):

Your question suggests that you think you can a function in the templates like a normal function (ie `activityperiod.objects.get(...)`).

You can't, the templating system is not made like this (for security reasons amongst others).

You should do something like, in your models:

```
def call_response(request):
    # ! first() not "all()" (if > 1 user, you'll have problem)!
    user = User.objects.first()
    activityperiod = activityperiod.objects.get(user=user)
    return render(request, "Test/list.html",
                  {"users":user ,"activityperiod":activityperiod})
```

Comment: from your code, I will get the information about only the first user. I want all user's data and from that data, I want to know the activity period of all users from the ActivityPeriod model, please suggest me. @Olivier Pons

Comment: Edit your question and add your models. `User` and `ActivityPeriod` to see their relationships

Answer (score 1):

views.py

```
def call_response(request):

user = User.objects.filter(user=request.user)
activityperiod = activityperiod.objects.get(user=user)
context={'user':user,'activityperiod':activityperiod}
return render(request, "Test/list.html",context})
```

Test/list.html

```
'real_name': {{ user.real_name}}
'activity_periods':{{ activityperiod.start_time }}
```